# Don't draw <hr> tag over background-image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have background image(small logo) that is defined like:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(icon.png);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 10%;
    }
</style>
```

And in html page I have `<hr>` tags, when I scroll down, line (defined by hr tag) is draw over background image, but I need to draw line and display image over line where image and line overlap (because of background image is small logo they overlap only partially).

Comment: If the `hr` is behind the background (so, practically speaking, invisible) why do you need it? Is the background transparent? If you don't want to see it, make it `display:none`.

Comment: Can you edit this codepen in a stackoverflow snippet to show us your problem: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/mXLwzp I just added an example image and put one <hr> in the code. What's the goal? Is the img fitting the whole size of the body? If yes, why do you need an hr, in this case it would be invisible, if the img is overlaying the <hr>?

Comment: @MrBuggy My background image is just logo, I need to show it at top left corner when I scroll down and line displayed over logo it produce visually not pleasant effect.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Becasue background image is just small logo and it only partially overlaps with line.

Comment: Does it really have to be a background image? Can't you make a div with an image, and use z-index to overlap things the way you want? (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/q6U3T/134/). I'm not sure if there's a way to bring a background image to the front.

Comment: Is the logo really a background-image for body or has it a wrapper like a div in a header?

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This solution make line invisible, but I need to draw line and display image over line where image and line overlap.

Comment: @mrgloom you should really update your question with this information.